# What are the pro and cons of hosting the twitter streaming api on Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)

Tags: twitter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, twitter-streaming-api

for a research project of mine I am writing an sentiment analysis tool for analyzing tweets.

My Question now is: What are the pro and cons of hosting the twitter streaming api on Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)?

Would the Micro (free) package be enough?
Does anyone have any experience with it in regards to twitter?

Thanks for you help

chris

Answer (score 1):

There can be many pros and cons regarding using Amazon Elastic computing (Amazon EC2). I suggest you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495582/amazon-ec2-as-web-server), Using twitter streaming API is definitely a subset of giving answers in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 is an virtual server like any other one just with a more dynamic pricing system then most of the traditional competitors. The biggest pro of Amazon web services is high reliability. On the other side it isn't very cheap. When you exactly know how much CPU and RAM capacity you will need I would recommend you a dedicated server. A often overlooked pro is the integration with other very useful Amazon webservices like DynamoDB and S3.

What's the best for your service completely depends on what you will need.

Comment: EC2 is quite a bit different than most virtual servers.  To get high-availability the application has to be written with a cloud deployment in mind (or at least refactored).